# How to correctly install CrashPlan backup software on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: backup, crashplan

I downloaded [CrashPlan for Linux](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/thankyou/?os=linux) and executed `sudo ./install.sh` inside the uncompressed archive.

CrashPlan wants to use the following installation settings:

```
CrashPlan will install to: /usr/local/crashplan
And put links to binaries in: /usr/local/bin
And store data in: /usr/local/var/crashplan
Your init.d dir is: /etc/init.d
Your current runlevel directory is: /etc/rc5.d
```

Are these settings correct to be used on Ubuntu 16.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's looking very reasonable.